# Is an update from Groovy to Hydro necessary to use Kinect?

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got a kinect and I am trying to follow the documentation http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/QuickStart
However, I get the following output.

> $  roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

> [openni.launch] is neither a launch file in package [openni_launch] nor is [openni_launch] a launch file name

I am currently on Groovy. Should I update to Hydro? If yes, How?
Or is it related to some other problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129456/is-an-update-from-groovy-to-hydro-necessary-to-use-kinect?/) by [expelliarmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/5244/expelliarmus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2014-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The OpenNI packages are available for Groovy. Try installing them with `sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-openni-launch`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [expelliarmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/5244/expelliarmus/) on 2014-02-14**:
Yes, I got that after posting this question. Thanks! :)